# Azure cognitive search multiple data source sync

Tags: c#, azure-sql-database, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

**Cosmos DB structure data source**

```
{
 "id":1,
 "anotherId":"3"
 "comment":"comment 1"
},
{
 "id":2,
 "anotherId":"3"
 "comment":"comment 2"
}
```

**Sql DB Structure data source**

```
{
 "anotherId":"3",
 "name":"test"
}
```

I want to merge the data source into one index like this

**Azure search index expected model**

```
{
 "id":1,
 "anotherId":"3"
 "comment":"comment 1",
 "name":"test"
},
{
 "id":2,
 "anotherId":"3"
 "comment":"comment 2",
  "name":"test"
}
```

I have followed this article
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources

The issue is, I could not map the "anotherId" with two data source indexer.

Comment: What do you mean by `I could not map the "anotherId" with two data source indexer.`?  Please edit your question and include the definition for your indexers.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @GauravMantri  i am using "anotherid" as the unique key to get data from different sources the issue is with cosmos db data. There is a "id" which is unique for comos db records but i can't use use "id" in indexer of cosmos db because i want to merge data with by "anotherid" and "anotherid" is not unique in cosmos data .

Comment: @GauravMantri as you can see the expected model, i need this kind of merge data in azure cognitive search

Comment: The behavior you want is that the "name": "test" in the SQL Data source should go with all instances of the "anotherId": "3" in the index?

Comment: @JenniferMarsman-MSFT yes

Answer (score 0):

The fundamental issue here is that you want to use "id" as your shared unique identifier (or key) in the search index, but the SQL data source doesn't know about that identifier.

From the [article you mentioned](https://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/tutorial-multiple-data-sources) (emphasis mine):

> In Azure Cognitive Search, the key field uniquely identifies each document. Every search index must have exactly one key field of type Edm.String. That key field must be present for each document in a data source that is added to the index. (In fact, it's the only required field.)

> When indexing data from multiple data sources, make sure **each incoming row or document contains a common document key to merge data from two physically distinct source documents into a new search document** in the combined index.

> **It often requires some up-front planning to identify a meaningful document key for your index, and make sure it exists in both data sources.** In this demo, the HotelId key for each hotel in Cosmos DB is also present in the rooms JSON blobs in Blob storage.

> In most cases, auto-generated document keys, such as those created by default by some indexers, **do not make good document keys for combined indexes**. In general you will want to use a meaningful, unique key value that already exists in, or can be easily added to, your data sources.

So, there are two potential workarounds that you could try:

1. In your search index, use "anotherId" as your key field, and change the "comment" field from type "Edm.String" to type "Collection(Edm.String)".  This is the simplest solution which will allow both the SQL indexer and the CosmosDB indexer to write to the search index.  Now, the tricky part of this option is that in order to write to the comment collection, you may have to do part of the 2nd solution below - use a custom skill to get all comments from the existing entry in the search index and merge them before reinserting into the search index.  See this comment from https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents:

> In primitive collections, if the document contains a Tags field of type Collection(Edm.String) with a value of ["budget"], and you execute a merge with a value of ["economy", "pool"] for Tag, the final value of the Tags field will be ["economy", "pool"]. It will not be ["budget", "economy", "pool"].

2. The other solution is to use a [custom skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/cognitive-search-create-custom-skill-example) in the SQL indexer (or just call this API directly in other code without the SQL indexer if you prefer) to update the search index using this [Add, Update, or Delete Document API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents) with the "mergeOrUpload" setting.  So you could continue to use the same search index, same CosmosDB indexer, and then change the SQL indexer in this fashion.  The custom skill code would need to get all entries from the search index where anotherId == "3" (use the [Search Documents API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents) for that) and then update them with "name" = "test" or whatever.

Hope this helps!